# Python MongoDB Motor dynamically create Indexes

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, asynchronous, pymongo, getattr

I am attempting to write a function which will async create Indexes for each of my collections dynamically. The struggle I am having is accessing the class instance of each of my collections, and then calling the object to create the index.

I have tried:

- getattr
- ast.literal_eval

**NOTE: I am unable to use eval() for security reasons**

Example of how my class instance looks:

```py
import ast
from models.database_models import IndexedKeyModels


class Mongo:  # pylint: disable=too-many-instance-attributes
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = self.get_set_connection() # Function to create MongoDB connection
        self.db = self.connection.pal_db
        self.test1 = self.db.test1
        self.test2 = self.db.test2

    async def set_indexes(self) -> None:

        test_string: str = ""
        if self.dev == "True":
            test_string += "test_"
        for name in IndexedKeyModels():
            await ast.literal_eval(
                f"self.{test_string}{name[0]}.create_index([('{name[1]}', {ASCENDING})], background=True)"
            )
```

The IndexedKeyModels looks like this:

```py
class IndexedKeyModels(BaseModel):
    """
    MongoDB Indexed Key names
    """

    test1: str = "Index1"
    test2: str = "Index2"
```

I would like to be able to dynamically create each Index for each collection without having to define each create_index for each collection we have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an index on a specific collection and field, you can do this programatically with this construct:

```
collectionname = 'coll1'
fieldname = 'field1'
db[collectionname].create_index([(fieldname , pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

Comment: thanks for responding with an answer.